# Angularjs + OAuth + Play 2.0

Tags: scala, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, playframework-2.0, angularjs

I'm learning Angularjs to create a single page application for a new project.
The back-end will be in Scala with Play 2.0 framework in a REST style API.
I would like to use FB, Twitter, Google, OpenId accounts has a way for the users to register and log in, but I don't know a lot about OAuth and how to make it work with Angular and Play 2.0 (of course I have started to read on OAuth).

Do you have any ideas of how to achieve that? Are there any libraties/tools to handle it? Or tutorial and examples?

EDIT: As pointed by Pere Villega, [SecureSocial](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial) seems a good options on the Play side, but it is follow a MVC pattern (view generated on the server) as opposed to angularjs + play which is more MVP (or MVVM) + REST api on the server. For Angular I found [Sapling](http://sapling.scotchmedia.com/). I have to figure out how to integrate the 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Secure Social](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial). Best invention since sliced bread. True story ;)

Comment: Thanks, it seems really good!How do I integrate it with angularjs, as it seems that Secure Social is a front end and back end solution?

Comment: There I can't help, I don't know Angular well enough, but SecurSocial removes all the Authentication issue, so it should be simple with that out of the way

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application

It shows you how to deal with accessing secured resources from an Angular perspective, all triggered from the client side. I think you could use Secure Social on the server with all of your REST API's behind `SecureAction` actions in the Play! controller.

I need to do something similar, but for now I'll use LDAP since it's a corporate application I'm building. Maybe I'll look at contributing LDAP/AD to Secure Social.